# How to duplicate entries in ExpressionEngine 3

Tags: ee3, duplicate

So I used MX Cloner in EE2 but it doesn't support EE3. 
Anyone know any tools for duplicating a channel entry in EE3? Need to create a few variations of landing pages.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in EE3. I have found SimpleCloner for EE3. It is given more option than MX Cloner.

See github link : https://github.com/ThorntonStuart/SimpleCloner

Answer (score 1):

The 2024 (and probably 2021 =) response to this is: You just have to [upgrade](https://creativearc.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-older-versions-of-expressionengine) to ExpressionEngine 7. It will clone entries natively.